# escaping greater-than and less-than in php echo inside server-side html

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to simply echo a function back to the client browser from a server php page after a selection has been made in a jQuery autocomplete box so that the function can process as needed (client-side) with the value of the autocomplete box. The autocomplete is in the php page as follows:

mypage.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete</title>   

    <link href="../../jqSuitePHP/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" id="skin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../../jqSuitePHP/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../jqSuitePHP/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>
        $(function ac_boxes() {

            $("#dlr").autocomplete({
                source: "dlrAutocompleteSearch.php",
                minLength: 2,
                search   : function(){$(this).addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');},
                open     : function(){$(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');},
                select: function( event, ui ) {

                    // Here's my attempt at calling the client side 'test' function
                    <?php echo '<script>window[test](ui.item.value)</script>;' ?>

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
---------
</body>
</html>
```

But the < and > are causing a problem. If I remove the < and >, the page processes completely (without the 'select' function of course. If I add the < and >, the page does not process.

I have tried assigning the string using the php htmlentities() as such:

```
<?php
$val = htmlentities('<script>window[test](ui.item.value)</script>;');
echo $val;
?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work either.

Is my problem stemming from the php being inside of the jQuery script? If so, what is another method of calling the php from the 'select' method of autocomplete?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: htmlentities converts character entities into the real characters (`&gt;` -> `>`). You want `htmlspecialchars()`, which encodes real characters into their entity equivalents (`>` -> `&gt;`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this code is doing what you think it is doing; when you load the page the PHP is executed and you end up with something like this in the source code:

```
<script>
...
select: function( event, ui ) {
    <script>window[test](ui.item.value)</script>;
}
...
</script>
```

Which is not correct (you don't need `script` tags within script tags; as you've seen it doesn't do anything but cause problems).

If you want to execute some PHP when the selection changes, you have to make another call to the server, via AJAX, submitting a form, or whatever. Something like this might be more like what you want:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    // send the selected value to the server for processing
    $.get("processChange.php", {value: ui.item.value});
}
```

See the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) on $.get() for more on that.

On the other hand, if all you're trying to do is call another client-side javascript function (`test`, for example) with the selected value, you don't need PHP to echo anything. This ought to do the trick:

```
<script>
function test(args) {
    // ...
}

$("#dlr").autocomplete({
    // ...
    select: function(event, ui) {
        test(ui.item.value);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. That makes sense about the php loading when the page loads causing a script tag inside a script. I did try the later example you have there just as a shot in the dark as the autocomplete script is on the server and the 'test()' is in the client's script. The result was 'method 'test' not found'. I hate to go the route of another request to another page for reasons of latency.

Comment: The autocomplete script is in a file included from the server? Can you put all the code in the same .js file?

Comment: No, the reason for putting the autocomplete scripting on the server is so the 'source:' for the autocomplete can be a php page that runs a query. The query does some pretty heavy lifting, so I didn't want the autocomplete on the client and have to use JSONP to do the receiving. The lag would be killer for the data sent.

Comment: You still will want your call to .autocomplete() to be on the client side though. Have you looked at examples on the [Jquery-UI website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)?

Comment: Yes, but if I put the autocomplete method in the client js, AJAX does not work because of the cross-domain issue. Only JSONP can be used at that point.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're getting at..?

Comment: Oh, OK. In that case, check out [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html). Maybe go back and edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` just like in HTML. You can also use the `replace()` function to find all the < and > and replace them.

Comment: Yeah, tried that. Both manually and by way of the htmlEntities() php function. No dice.